# Show that the sum of series is finite

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $(S_n)_n$ be the sequence defined by
$$S_n = \left(\sum_{r = 0}^n r^{\alpha}\right)^{-\beta},$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta \geq 0$.

I would like to know if $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} S_n$ is finite if $(\alpha+1)\beta > 1$. I can show this by assuming that $\alpha = 0$, $\alpha = 1$, or $\alpha = 2$. But I need a general proof.

Comment: Hint: for large $n$, $S_n\sim(\alpha+1)^{\beta}n^{-\beta(\alpha+1)}$. Now compare to $n^{-\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: Thanks. There was a typo in my post. I updated. But got your point. So how to you show that $\sum r^{\alpha} \sim ({\alpha + 1})n^{\alpha+1}$?

Comment: It's $\sum r^\alpha\sim n^{\alpha+1}/(\alpha+1)$, actually. It follows by comparison to the integral $\int_0^nx^\alpha dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asymptotically, when $n$ is large, $\sum_{r=0}^{n} r^\alpha\sim \frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}$
$$S_n\sim \frac{(\alpha+1)^\beta}{n^{\alpha\beta+\beta}}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty S_n \sim (\alpha+1)^\beta\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha\beta+\beta}}$$

Since $\alpha\beta>1\Rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is convergent, hence finite.